# Issue with SharePoint Migration Assessment Tool: Failing in pre-validation check

Tags: migration

We are trying to run SharePoint Migration Assessment tool given by microsoft, but it is failing in pre validation with below error.

> Failed to populate property mappings. This is typically caused by the
>   proxy group not containing a User Profile Service Application, or the
>   user not having enough permissions to the User Profile Service
>   Application. Add the user to the Sharing Permissions on the User
>   Profile Service Application with Full Control and try again.

[image]

The account from which we are running this tool is already added in Farm Administrator Group, Administrator for User Profile Service Application and in Permission of User Profile service application with Full control.

Can someone please guide on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check Application Proxy Groups. Maybe the User Profile Service Application is missing from default group.

Using PowerShell:

```
# Prevent output trimming (...)
$FormatEnumerationLimit = -1

# Get list of proxy groups
Get-SPServiceApplicationProxyGroup | select FriendlyName, Proxies | fl
```

Using Central Administration:

```
Application Management > Service Applications > Configure service application associations
```